# My submit buttons are not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

After submitting the buttons, it doesn't redirect to another page. Can someone please help to find the error in this code and why my buttons typ1 and cod does not redirect to the location which I already given.

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    include("common.php");?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function cd()
    {
        document.getElementById('credit').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('debit').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('net').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('cash').style.display='none';
    }
    function db()
    {
        document.getElementById('debit').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('credit').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('net').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('cash').style.display='none';
    }
    function ns()
    {
        document.getElementById('net').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('debit').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('credit').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('cash').style.display='none';
    }
    function cs()
    {
        document.getElementById('cash').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('debit').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('credit').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('net').style.display='none';
    }
    function validate(inputtxt)
    {

        var card1 = /^(?:3[47][0-9]{13})$/;  
      if(inputtxt.value.match(card1))  
            {  
          return true;  
            }  
          else  
            {  
            alert("Not a  credit card number!");  
            return false;  
            }  
        if(card1.length!=16)
        {
            alert("Only 16 digits are allowed");
            return false;
        }


    }
    </script>
    <style>
    .d2
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #242222;
        padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
        font-family: Arial; 
        font-style:;
    }
    .tab{
        width:100%;
        height: 400px;
        padding:25px 10px 10px 25px;
        font-size: 25px;
         padding:15px;
        border:1px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;

    }
    #credit
    {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    padding :25px 15px 15px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    }
    #debit{
        width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    padding :25px 15px 15px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    }
    #net{
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        padding :25px 15px 15px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    }
    #cash{
        width:600px;
        height:100%;
        padding :25px 15px 15px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    }
    .card{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head><body>
    <form method="post">
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['sum']))
    {
       $s1=$_SESSION['sum']; 
    echo "
    <div class='d2'> Make Payment</div>
    <div>
    <table class='tab'><tr><td><button name='cr' style='padding: 14px 20px 14px 20px;font-size:15px;color:white;width:300px;background-color:#373535;cursor:pointer;border-radius:5px;border-color:#363434;border-collapse:collapse;font-weight:inherit;' class= 'c1' onclick='cd()'>Credit Card</button>
    <br/>
    <button name='dr' class='d1' style='padding: 14px 20px 14px 20px;font-size:15px;color:white;width:300px;background-color:#373535;cursor:pointer;border-radius:5px;border-color:#363434;border-collapse:collapse;font-weight:inherit;' onclick='db()'>Debit  Card</button>
    <br/>
    <button name='nb' class='n1' style='padding: 14px 20px 14px 20px;font-size:15px;color:white; width:300px; background-color:#373535;cursor:pointer;border-radius:5px;border-color:#363434;border-collapse:collapse;font-weight:inherit;' onclick='ns()'>Net Banking</button>
    <br/>
    <button name='cash' style='padding: 14px 20px 14px 20px;font-size:15px;color:white;background-color:#373535;width:300px; cursor:pointer;border-radius:5px;border-color:#363434;border-collapse:collapse;font-weight:inherit;'onclick='cs()'>Cash On Delivery</button>
    </td>
    <td ><div id='credit' > <h2>Pay using Credit</h2>
    <hr>
    <label>Card number :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='card'><input type='text' name='cardno' placeholder='Card number' required='true'/></span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Expiry Date:</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type'text' name='month' placeholder='MM' required='true'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type'text' name='year' placeholder='YY' required='true'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type'text' name='cvv' placeholder='CVV' required='true'/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button type='submit' name='typ1'  style='padding: 14px 35px 14px 35px;font-size:15px;color:white;background-color:#ED0C5B;cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:5px;border-color:#ED0C5B;border-collapse:collapse;font-weight:inherit;'>
    <center>Pay Rs. $s1</center></button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>This card will be save for faster payment.</label>
    </div>
    <div id='debit' style='display:none' > <h2>Pay using Debit Card</h2>
    <hr>
    <label>Card number :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' name='cardno'  placeholder='Card number' required='true'/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Expiry Date:</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type'text' name='mm' placeholder='MM' required='true'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type'text' name='yy' placeholder='YY' required='true'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type'text' name='cvv' placeholder='CVV' required='true'>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button type='submit' style='padding: 14px 35px 14px 35px;font-size:15px;color:white;background-color:#ED0C5B;cursor:pointer;border-radius:5px;border-color:#ED0C5B;border-collapse:collapse;font-weight:inherit;'><center>Pay Rs. $s1</center></button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>This card will be save for faster payment.</label>
    </div>
    <div id='net' style='display:none'> <h2>Pay using Net Banking</h2>
    <hr/>
    <label>Select Bank:</label><input type='radio' value='ICICI'>ICICI &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' value='HDFC'>
    HDFC&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' value='Axis'>Axis
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Account number :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='card'>
    <input type='text' name='cardno' placeholder='Enter your Account number' required='true'/>
    </span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button type='submit'  style='padding: 14px 35px 14px 35px;font-size:15px;color:white;background-color:#ED0C5B;cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:5px;border-color:#ED0C5B;border-collapse:collapse;font-weight:inherit;'><center>Pay Rs. $s1</center></button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>This card will be save for faster payment.</label>
    </div>
    <div id='cash' style='display:none'> <h2>Pay using Cash On Delivery</h2>
    <hr width=100%/>
    <button  name='cod' type='submit' style='padding: 14px 35px 14px 35px;font-size:15px;color:white;background-color:#ED0C5B;cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:5px;border-color:#ED0C5B;border-collapse:collapse;font-weight:inherit;'>
    Place COD Order</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>This card will be save for faster payment.</label>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </div>
    ";


    }
    ?>
    </form></body></html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['typ1']))
    {
        $_SESSION['s2']=$_SESSION['sum'];
        $card=$_POST['cardno'];
        $mon=$_POST['month'];
        $yr=$_POST['year'];
        $cv=$_POST['cvv'];
        $_SESSION['card']=$card;
        $q7="select * from bank where card_no=$card";
       $qry6= mysql_query($q7);
       while($r7=mysql_fetch_array($qry6))
       {
        $m=$r7[3];
        $y=$r7[4];
        $c=$r7[5];
        $money=$r7[6];
        if($mon==$m && $yr==$y && $cv==$c)
        {

                header("location:redirect.php");

        }
        else{
            echo "<script>alert('Your details doesnot match');</script>";
        }
       }

    }
    if(isset($_POST['cod']))
    {
        header("location:cod.php");
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you didn't write which page form submit.

```
<form method="post"><!-- action="isWhere" -->
```

Also you can write your code like this. I think this way is better than your wrote.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['sum']))
{
   $s1=$_SESSION['sum'];
?>

<form method="post" action="isWhere">...</form>

<?php
}
?>
```